# Importance of randomness in Kruskal's algorithm for maze generation

Tags: algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

I have an assignment where I need to create a maze from a grid of cells.
I successfully did it using the [Randomized Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Randomized_Kruskal.27s_algorithm) as described on the Wiki page and using a [Disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).
Now the assignment ask me to do the same but instead of picking cells in a random order I just start at the top left of the grid and browse all the cells in order until I reach the bottom left.
The modified algorithm seems to work just fine and I don't notice any major difference with the Randomized Kruskal's algorithm.

So my question is: what is the importance of picking elements in a random order in the Randomized Kruskal's algorithm ? Is there any maze that could be created by the randomized version but could not using the non-random one ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Both can create all mazes, but the distributions will be different.